# Erlang: How to create a function that returns a string containing the date in YYMMDD format?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, erlang-shell

I am trying to learn Erlang and I am working on the practice problems Erlang has on the site. One of them is:

**Write the function time:swedish_date() which returns a string containing the date in swedish YYMMDD format:**

```
time:swedish_date()
"080901"
```

My function:

```
-module(demo).
-export([swedish_date/0]).

swedish_date() ->
[YYYY,MM,DD] = tuple_to_list(date()),
string:substr((integer_to_list(YYYY, 3,4)++pad_string(integer_to_list(MM))++pad_string(integer_to_list(DD)).

pad_string(String) ->
if 
    length(String) == 1 -> '0' ++ String;
    true -> String
end.
```

I'm getting the following errors when compiled.

```
demo.erl:6: syntax error before: '.'
demo.erl:2: function swedish_date/0 undefined
demo.erl:9: Warning: function pad_string/1 is unused 
error
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

After fixing your compilation errors, you're still facing runtime errors. Since you're trying to learn Erlang, it's instructive to look at your approach and see if it can be improved, and fix those runtime errors along the way.

First let's look at `swedish_date/0`:

```
swedish_date() ->
    [YYYY,MM,DD] = tuple_to_list(date()),
```

Why convert the list to a tuple? Since you use the list elements individually and never use the list as a whole, the conversion serves no purpose. You can instead just pattern-match the returned tuple:

```
    {YYYY,MM,DD} = date(),
```

Next, you're calling `string:substr/1`, which doesn't exist:

```
    string:substr((integer_to_list(YYYY,3,4) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(MM)) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(DD))).
```

The [`string:substr/2,3` functions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#substr-2) both take a starting position, and the 3-arity version also takes a length. You don't need either, and can avoid `string:substr` entirely and instead just return the assembled string:

```
    integer_to_list(YYYY,3,4) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(MM)) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(DD)).
```

Whoops, this is still not right: there is no such function `integer_to_list/3`, so just replace that first call with `integer_to_list/1`:

```
    integer_to_list(YYYY) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(MM)) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(DD)).
```

Next, let's look at `pad_string/1`:

```
pad_string(String) ->
    if
        length(String) == 1 -> '0' ++ String;
        true -> String
    end.
```

There's a runtime error here because `'0'` is an atom and you're attempting to append `String`, which is a list, to it. The error looks like this:

> ** exception error: bad argument
>        in operator  ++/2
>           called as '0' ++ "8"

Instead of just fixing that directly, let's consider what `pad_string/1` does: it adds a leading `0` character if the string is a single digit. Instead of using `if` to check for this condition — `if` isn't used that often in Erlang code — use pattern matching:

```
pad_string([D]) ->
    [$0,D];
pad_string(S) ->
    S.
```

The first clause matches a single-element list, and returns a new list with the element `D` preceded with `$0`, which is the character constant for the character `0`. The second clause matches all other arguments and just returns whatever is passed in.

Here's the full version with all changes:

```
-module(demo).
-export([swedish_date/0]).

swedish_date() ->
    {YYYY,MM,DD} = date(),
    integer_to_list(YYYY) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(MM)) ++
        pad_string(integer_to_list(DD)).

pad_string([D]) ->
    [$0,D];
pad_string(S) ->
    S.
```

But a simpler approach would be to use [the `io_lib:format/2` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io_lib.html#format-2) to just format the desired string directly:

```
swedish_date() ->
    io_lib:format("~w~2..0w~2..0w", tuple_to_list(date())).
```

First, note that we're back to calling `tuple_to_list(date())`. This is because the second argument for `io_lib:format/2` must be a list. Its first argument is a format string, which in our case says to expect three arguments, formatting each as an Erlang term, and formatting the 2nd and 3rd arguments with a width of 2 and 0-padded.

But there's still one more step to address, because if we run the `io_lib:format/2` version we get:

```
1> demo:swedish_date().
["2015",["0",56],"29"]
```

Whoa, what's that? It's simply a deep list, where each element of the list is itself a list. To get the format we want, we can flatten that list:

```
swedish_date() ->
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~w~2..0w~2..0w", tuple_to_list(date()))).
```

Executing this version gives us what we want:

```
2> demo:swedish_date().
"20150829"
```

Find the final full version of the code below.

```
-module(demo).
-export([swedish_date/0]).

swedish_date() ->
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~w~2..0w~2..0w", tuple_to_list(date()))).
```

**UPDATE**: @Pascal comments that the year should be printed as 2 digits rather than 4. We can achieve this by passing the date list through a list comprehension:

```
swedish_date() ->
    DateVals = [D rem 100 || D <- tuple_to_list(date())],
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~w~2..0w~2..0w", DateVals)).
```

This applies the `rem` remainder operator to each of the list elements returned by `tuple_to_list(date())`. The operation is needless for month and day but I think it's cleaner than extracting the year and processing it individually. The result:

```
3> demo:swedish_date().
"150829"
```

Comment: it prints "20150829", not "150829", its why I used YYYY rem 100.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. You are missing a parenthesis at the end of line 6.
2. You are trying to call `integer_to_list/3` when Erlang only defines `integer_to_list/1,2`.

This will work:

```
-module(demo).
-export([swedish_date/0]).

swedish_date() ->
[YYYY,MM,DD] = tuple_to_list(date()),
string:substr(
    integer_to_list(YYYY) ++ 
    pad_string(integer_to_list(MM)) ++ 
    pad_string(integer_to_list(DD))
    ).

pad_string(String) ->
if 
    length(String) == 1 -> '0' ++ String;
    true -> String
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the parenthesis error on line 6, you also have an error on line 10 where yo use the form '0' instead of "0", so you define an atom rather than a string.

I understand you are doing this for educational purpose, but I encourage you to dig into erlang libraries, it is something you will have to do. For a common problem like this, it already exists function that help you:

```
swedish_date() ->
    {YYYY,MM,DD} = date(), % not useful to transform into list
    lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~2.10.0B~2.10.0B~2.10.0B",[YYYY rem 100,MM,DD])).
    % ~X.Y.ZB means: uses format integer in base Y, print X characters, uses Z for padding
```